# Other values of mass of the electron and the charge of the electron?

Tags: mass, electrons, charge

Are there whatever experimental data other than Millikan Oil Droplet experiments data and Stoney calculations from electrolysis low, or some experimental indications pointed on the possibility that the mass of the electron and the charge of the electron can be larger than we known from textbooks ? And, we are not consider moving electron in SRT.

Comment: well the values that are on the textbooks are the values that have been *experimentally* measured...
The charge of the electron actually depends on the energy at which you are probing it though, as the higher the energy the more non-negligible terms you have in the Feynman diagram expansion (more energy => creates more virtual particles, that "shield" the bare charge of the electron and effectively reduce it, if you are looking from outside this virtual cloud. With high energy, you can 'break through' and you see a smaller charge).

Comment: As far as the mass is concerned, there is something called the *effective* mass, which can be very different from the nominal mass of the electron. It basically comes from incorporating into Newton II the interaction between the electron (of well known mass m) with its surroundings (e.g. a crystal), which results in an artifical 'm' term, called the effective mass.
Is the kind of things that you are looking for, or is your question aiming at a different answer? What's SRT? Special Relaitity...?

Comment: @SuperCiocia, I am looking for pure experimental evidences, not theoretical. Yes, special relativity. My expectation is to have some evidence that these two parameters can be larger.

Comment: Maybe and likely some data from the past when physicists have only started to ask themselves what are the mass and the charge of the electron ?

Comment: Experimentally, the charge of the electron was measured with the Millikan Oil Droplet experiment, while the mass-to-charge ratio was measured via Helmholz coils. You can read up on that. As far as I know, no one has found any deviations yet, and they measure them pretty precisely nowadays...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Our knowledge of these properties comes from experiments, not books.

Comment: No questions about the charge to mass ratio, this value was determined independently on the charge and mass (by Thompson, first). Charge of electron came from the Millikan Oil Droplet experiment and Stoney calculations from electrolysis low.  Mass was calculated from the charge to mass ratio and the charge from the Millikan’s value. So, my question is on measurements  of the charge and reliability of Millikan experiments data. I need other experiments on electron charge than from Millikan and Stoney. Some more examples ?

Comment: @SuperCiocia You are the first in this forum talking about shielded charge due to its velocity. I was driven into the ground for an [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168684/where-do-photons-go-when-they-are-absorbed/168785#168785) to the question "Where do photons go then they are absorbed?". Is my answer wrong for all time?

Comment: @SuperCiocia In the Millikan Oil Droplet experiment the measured charge is the charge of monovalent ion (a minimal change of ionised oil drop). So, to be exact, electron charge is actually is the charge of monovalent ion and it is not necessary that charge of electron is equal to charge of monovalent ion.

Answer (score 1):

People have certainly measured the electron's charge and mass more than once in the last 100 years. See for example [this table](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2014-rev-phys-constants.pdf) from the Particle Data Group, where you can find the constants you want to around 8 significant digits, much more than what was possible for Millikan. For comparison, Wikipedia claims that Millikan and Fletcher measured $e$ to be $1.5924(17) \times 10^{-19}\ \mathrm{C}$, while the table I linked gives a value of $1.602\, 176\, 565(35)\times 10^{-19}\ \mathrm{C}$, around 0.6% higher. Rest assured that any data you find in textbooks is very likely to contain relatively recent measurements, unless the textbook was written a century ago.

Comment: One may add that in the link you provide there is a link with  a searchable bibliography that gives the experiments which were used to derive the values http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/Citations/Search.html