# Where else than Atoms do Photons Disappear and Reappear from?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, visible-light, subatomic

Where does photons come from and disappear to? Can photons be destroyed and created? Without atoms would photons exist? What other ways then from atoms can photons be made?

Comment: Yes, photons can be "destroyed" and created.

Comment: This one might help a bit: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168684/

Comment: Reasonable question.  An unusual answer see here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168684/where-do-photons-go-when-they-are-absorbed/168785#168785 . Unfortunately it is without any criticism downvoted so it is not possible to see, what is wrong.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The problem with that answer is that we already have a quantum theory of radiation that has been verified to an enormous degree of precision ... perhaps (and arguably) standing with special relativity as the top two best-tested theories.  Your ideas don't improve on what we already have.

Comment: @garyp Thanks for answering. Please, could you read chapter about proton-electron-interaction in atoms? This is really new and give an explanation about electron "orbitals". Let us chat?

Comment: In the case of the comment above "unusual" means "not even wrong".

Comment: @Danu could you help in restructuring my question so I can reopen it?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler could you help in restructuring my question so I can reopen it?

Comment: @HritikNarayan  could you help in restructuring my question so I can reopen it?

Comment: @garyp could you help in restructuring my question so I can reopen it?

Comment: @Jen why do you want to reopen it?

Comment: @MitchellPorter because to broad is not the case. How many ways can photons be made?

Comment: Someone took the time to answer it other than me.

Comment: OK... "How many ways can photons be made?" Any charged particle can emit or absorb a photon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Photons mediate the electromagnetic force.  Atoms are not necessary for photons to exist. You just need charged particles (electrons, protons, etc) to interact with each other from a distance.

There are many ways for a photon to be created and destroyed.  Depending upon its wavelength, as it propagates in free space , it could "disappear" and a pair electron-positron could be created in its place.  An atom could absorb it, and if it is part of a solid, it could couple its excited energy to a phonon and then create heat.

Comment: @igael could you help in restructuring my question so I can reopen it?

Comment: could you help in restructuring my question so I can reopen it?